# pagenote: suppressing note number in text

Tags: numbering, pagenote

How does one suppress all marks in the text?

Currently I have in the Preamble:

```
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\section*{\notesname\ to chapter~\thechapter}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{}
```

And in the text: `\pagenote{...}`

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you tell if my answer helped?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation mentions `\notenumintext`, that by default prints its argument in `\textsuperscript`. Redefine it to do nothing with its argument and you're done.

How can the reader guess what the endnote refer to? I don't know.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\section*{\notesname\ to chapter~\thechapter}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{}
\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

x\pagenote{This was an x}
y\pagenote{This was an y}

\chapter*{Notes}

\printnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]